# Open Excel from Powershell, running from Task scheduler

Tags: powershell, task-scheduler, microsoft-excel

**What I'm trying to do:**

I want a scheduled task to refresh Excel queries (ODBC), save them, and email them to clients.

**What I got so far:**

I have a PowerShell script that runs opens an Excel file and runs a VBA macro from it.
the VBA macro opens the relevant files, refreshes any queries, and saves them.
Then the PowerShell script reads sends the files to clients, as email attachments.
All this works fine, as long as I run it from the PowerShell window.
It also works file after I created a task for it in Windows Task Scheduler, and set it to run only when user is logged on.

**The error:**

When I set the scheduled task to run whether user is logged on or not (with storing password because I want to send the email), I get the error "Microsoft Excel cannot access the file".

**Things I tried and didn't help:**

Putting it on a local HD, setting read-write access to everyone, checking "Run with highest privileges" in Task Scheduler, all options in "configure for" of Task scheduler, setting the task for a different user (with his password), using a short path (read somewhere that there's a limit of 30 characters). I know the PowerShell script runs because it creates a log file.

Comment: You'd probably have to show me the logic and I might be able to help. Probably the PowerShell logic that manipulates the xls and the macro logic too.